# installing in-house apps stuck/looping on iOS 7

Tags: cordova, ios7, phonegap-build

I create an in-house apps using enterprise plan.I facing a problem when install apps in ios7 it pop up 2 same apps ,1 is installing and another 1 is finish.I install the apps via link

```
 <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.mysite.com/install.plist">
```

and my plist are

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
<key>items</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://www.mysite.com/myApps.ipa</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>full-size-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <false/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>www.mysite.com/apps/icons/ios/icon-72.png</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>display-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <false/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://www.mysite.com/apps/icons/ios/icon.png</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.myapps.myapps</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>myApps</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

All my url is correct that why it work on ios 6 but after upgraded to iOS7 no longer install perfectly.Can any 1 help?Below is Sample image

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm having the same issue with our in-house app.  I did notice when we moved from ad-hoc, where the app just installed in-place, to in-house, the app installs in the 'installing...' space, then actually occupies the next available springboard space (so -- Apple's copying the bundle from some temporary spot, then either isn't deleting the old bundle, or the springboard isn't cleaning up the icon).

SOOOO....  I just went and edited my manifest.  I noticed the Bundle ID didn't *exactly* match the bundle ID in the app (because I changed it when I switched from AdHoc to In-House, e.g. com.mycompany.myapp to com.mycompany.myapp.enterprise).  After making the bundle id match exaclty the app actually installs exactly in-place (no actual app icon next to the "installing..." icon as it's copied -- or whatever it's doing).  8^)

Let me know if that works for you!

MBPro x 4, MacMini x 2, iMac, iPhone x 5, iPad x 2, NeXT Cube w/ NeXT Dimension, NeXT Station.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help somebody:  Were were using "over the air" installation via the itms-services protocol, which involved using a .plist file in association with the .ipa file.  On the iPhone there must be some caching going on, because the only way we could get the installation to work was to rename the .plist file to break any existing cache.

Part of the reason this happened was because in our last deployment, the bundle-identifiers changed, but the updated bundle-identifier was not being read by the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Install operation of app was looping/Stuck. After spending quite a time on this, the problem was discovered in my Adhoc distribution profile on member center(Web portal). Profile somehow was in invalid state(don't know the reason for this). Upon regenerating the profile everything was sorted out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting Settings App > general > reset> reset privacy and restarting helped me